# Display exact value of a variable in R

Tags: r, r-faq

```
> x <- 1.00042589212565
> x
[1] 1.000426
```

If I wanted to print the exact value of `x`, how would I do it?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I tried Googling for "R" and "exact" or "round" but all I get are articles about how to round.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it isn't a whole number then you won't get an exact value, just an approximation.  See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: *exactly* The only truly exact value is the 8-bytes of a mantissa/exponent encoded floating-point value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Globally solution during all the session

```
options(digits=16)
> x
[1] 1.00042589212565
```

or locally just for x:

```
sprintf("%.16f", x)
[1] "1.0004258921256499"
```

Comment: I like the second one, which shows nicely that "exact" is relative.

Answer (score 8):

```
print(x, digits=15)
```

or

```
format(x, digits=15)
```

or

```
sprintf("%.14f", x)
```